# Getting ImportError Using "flask run"

Tags: python, flask, pipenv

I'm creating a Flask RESTful API. Here's the project structure:

```
│   .env
│   .flaskenv
│   .gitignore
│   <App Name>.code-workspace
│   <App Name>.py
│   dev_start
│   LICENSE
│   Pipfile
│   Pipfile.lock
│   README.md
│
├───<App Name>_api
    │   errors.py
    │   settings.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───crypto
    │       password.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───models
    │       blacklisted_token.py
    │       company.py
    │       user.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───resources
    │       company.py
    │       messages.py
    │       user.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───schemas
            company.py
            user.py
            __init__.py
```

Here's the .flaskenv file:

```
FLASK_APP=<App Name>:create_app()
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=1
FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000
FLASK_RUN_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

The "App Name" folder's "**init**.py" file has the "create_app" function defined. When I try to do a "pipenv run flask run" I get the following error:

```
Loading .env environment variables...
 * Serving Flask app '<App Name>' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing '<App Name>', an ImportError was raised.
```

What's really confusing is that there isn't an explanation of the ImportError.

Thanks in advance for any help. I've been searching for hours trying to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

In your .ENV:

```
FLASK_APP=<App Name>:create_app()
```

Try to replace with:

```
FLASK_APP=<App Name>:create_app
```

The possible reason is when you load the module you need to point on `app` variable or `callable` that return `app`.